# jquery post + serializeArray

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to use jquery post + serializeArray() to post a form containing photo field to another php page for processing like this but it doesn't work:-

```
<script>
function photo_process(){
     $.post('album/photoprocess.php',$('#form2').serializeArray(),
          function (output){
              $('#result_message').html(output);           
          }
     );
}
</script>

<form id="form2" action="module/album/photoprocess.php" method="post" 
      enctype="multipart/form-data">
…
…
</form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="photo_process()"/>

<div id="result_message"></div>
```

Actually, can I do so? or I just have written something incorrectly?? thanks!

Comment: what data do you need to send to your album/photoprocess.php file??

Answer (score 0):

Use `.serialize()` instead of `.serializeArray()`

Comment: what is problem with [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) ?

Comment: I can post some non image data to the next page, but not for the image data... what can I do?? Thanks!

Comment: what do you mean by image data try to input more snippet from your code.

Comment: Jquery's ajax doesn't allow files sending. File inputs can't be serialized